# How to define a identical number for all identical URLs at the string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a string like this:

```
var str = "this is [link1][1]
           this is [link2][2]

           this is [link3][3]
           this is [link4][4]

           [1]: http://example1.com

           [2]: http://example2.com
           [3]: http://example1.com


           [4]: http://example4.com";
```

Now I want this:

```
var str = "this is [link1][1]
           this is [link2][2]

           this is [link3][1]
           this is [link4][4]

           [1]: http://example1.com
           [2]: http://example2.com
           [4]: http://example4.com";
```

As you see in the above example there is two things:

1. Removing redundant `\n` between all those URLs (**only** URLs)
2. Remove duplicate URLs and replace refrence-number.(In other word, in the example above, because first and third URLs are the same, then `[3]: http://example1.com` removed and `[3]` replaced with `[1]`)

---

There is a regex which matches `[any digit]:` and its `url` in two groups:

```
/(\[[0-9]*]:)\s*(.*)\r?\n?/gm
```

In the `str`, that regex matches:

```
//group1
$1: [1]:
    [2]:
    [3]:
    [4]:

//group2
$2: http://example1.com
    http://example2.com
    http://example1.com
    http://example4.com
```

---

Also there is another regex which remove all waste `\n` between only links:

```
str.replace(/(^\[[0-9]*]:.*)\n+/gm, $1\n);
```

---

Well, How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a solution for yout problem:

```
function removeMultipleMatkdownLinks(markownString) {
  var seperateLinks = /(\[[0-9]*]):\s*(.*)\r?\n?/gm;
  var removeNewLines = /(^\[[0-9]*]:.*)\n+/gm; 

  var result;
  var urls = [], ids = [];
  var formattedString = str;
  while ((result = seperateLinks.exec(str)) !== null) {
      if (result.index === seperateLinks.lastIndex) {
          result.lastIndex++;
      }
      //check if link already exists
      var index = urls.indexOf(result[2]);
      if(index < 0) {
        urls.push(result[2]);
        ids.push(result[1]);

      } else { //remove links and replace ids
        var removeLink = new RegExp("(\\" + result[1] + ":.*\\r?\\n?)", "gm"); ///(\[1\]:.*\n)/gm
        var changeNumber = new RegExp("(\\" + result[1] + ")", "gm");
        formattedString = formattedString
          .replace(removeLink, "")
          .replace(changeNumber, ids[index]);
      }
  }

  return formattedString.replace(removeNewLines, "$1\n");
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5jLz67hq/)